Newlib cannot be used properly
i am facing issues with newlib, i compiled my code with gcc cross-compiler, and when i use Newlib to printf, my linker will tell me that printf isn't declared
My compiling and linking script:
i686-elf-gcc -c src/userland/umain/umain.c -o output/file/umain.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -I "include/include"

i686-elf-gcc -T src/linker.ld -o output/isolate/RCMiracle.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib output/file/umain.o output/file/gdt.o output/file/enter.o output/file/function.o output/file/boot.o output/file/kernel.o output/file/jump.o -lgcc -I "include/include"

My code:
#include <stdio.h>
void umain() {
    printf("hello world");
}

Newlib and cross-compiler issues

In your linker command, where is the arg that says to link against newlib? (e.g. -lnewlib or equivalent)

I don't have it in my linker command, but i think that use only -I include/include is ok

No! You have to tell the linker explicitly what libraries to use [and where they are] because you specified -nostdlib. -I is just to specify the directories to search when looking for .h files during compilation. It has nothing to do with specifying which libraries to link with [or where to find them].

You are trying to create software to run in a realtime/embedded environment but seem not to know the basics of building a C program. realtime/embedded programming is difficult. Too difficult for a first C project. I'd get more experience in basic/general C application programming before trying to do this advanced project.
